# How do I remove redundancy in this clojure code?

Tags: clojure

I have written the following code:

```
(defprotocol MusicFile
    (get-artist [this])
    (get-song [this])
    (get-album [this]))


(defrecord Mp3 [filename]
    MusicFile
    (get-artist [this]
        (let [info (get-all-info (:filename this))]
            (:artist info)))
    (get-song [this]
        (let [info (get-all-info (:filename this))]
            (:title info)))
    (get-album [this]
        (let [info (get-all-info (:filename this))]
            (:album info))))
```

Is there a easyway to remove redundancy in this code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fields of the record are in scope within methods defined inside the record definition.

```
(defrecord Mp3 [filename]
    MusicFile
    (get-artist [this]
      (:artist (get-all-info filename)))
    (get-song [this]
      (:title (get-all-info filename)))
    (get-album [this]
      (:album (get-all-info filename))))
```

Comment: Is there a possibility to make a generic accessor so that you can define get-artist like `(get-artist [this] (get-field this :artist))` ?

Comment: you could easily write a function that does that

Comment: `(defn get-field [k t] (get (get-all-info (:filename t)) k))`